# How to find out if more then one checkbox was selected

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a problem with validation in JSP. I need to check a few check boxes, if a user selects two check-boxes it should show an alert message. One - throwing data on controller and redirect to another page. Null - redirect to another page only. How can I achieve this?

```
 <form method="post">
                <tr th:each="data : ${allData}">
                    <div>
                        <td th:text="${data.id}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.someString}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.someInt}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.someDecimal}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${data.someDate}"></td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="id" id="check" type="checkbox" th:value="${data.id}"/>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <button formaction="/delete" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">Delete</button>
                <button formaction="#" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">Edit</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what you need: (UPDATED)**

```
var number_checked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
if (number_checked > 1) {
    //bla bla bla
} else if (number_checked == 1) {
    //bla bla bla
} else {
    //bla bla bla
}
```

## Good luck!